# MeteorJS: Having a hard time understanding collections

Tags: mongodb, collections, meteor

I am a newb to MeteorJS and I am building an app that plots points on a Google Map (using their API) based on an XML api service and when clicking on one of those points, detailed information will be displayed. Pretty straight forward.

What I am struggling with is that I need to store the API results so that the API isn't pinged every time the page is loaded and since Meteor uses MongoDB, I thought of storing the results in a collection, but I am just not sure I understand how to use them.

Here is what a the XML feed will look like:

```
<api version="1.0">
    <id>597837338</id>
    <time>3/6/2014 11:46:46 PM</time>
    <machine>query://djsearch6/dejobs</machine>
    <query>sales OR marketing</query>
    <recordcount>500</recordcount>
    <startrow>1</startrow>
    <endrow>10</endrow>
    <order>relevance</order>
    <jobs>
    <job>
        <title>
        Customer Service Representative - State Farm Agent Team Member (Property and Casualty Insurance Focus)
        </title>
        <url>http://my.jobs/a897284496c14249a8473d5947d08b4d321</url>
        <company>Cie Taylor - State Farm Agent</company>
        <location>Mesa, AZ</location>
        <dateacquired>2014-1-19 1:31 AM</dateacquired>
        <jvid>a897284496c14249a8473d5947d08b4d321</jvid>
    </job>
    <job>
        <title>
        Insurance and Financial Services Position - State Farm Agent Team Member (Sales experience preferred)
        </title>
        <url>http://my.jobs/1b717b9492464fbabbd22d3c0e8cf08d321</url>
        <company>Cie Taylor - State Farm Agent</company>
        <location>Mesa, AZ</location>
        <dateacquired>2014-1-19 1:31 AM</dateacquired>
        <jvid>1b717b9492464fbabbd22d3c0e8cf08d321</jvid>
    </job>
  </jobs>
</api>
```

Comment: What is the question then, because this does not seem to be one as yet. Perhaps add what you want to achieve. Also since you are using JavaScript, can you not just return JSON from the service API? It will be easier to deal with.

Comment: @NeilLunn - Sorry for the vague "question" (or lack of one). Let me re-word my question. Also, the API returns XML, no support for JSON :(

Comment: Once you read the data from that XML, is where your problems appear?

Answer (score 1):

I think this could give you a general idea, if I don´t have understand your question in the correct way, my apologies:

For parsing from XML to JSON: http://davidwalsh.name/convert-xml-json

First parse the XML to a JSON, for example imagine this JSON extracted from XML:

```
var dataFromXML = {
    "company": 597837338,
    "createdAt": "3/6/2014 11:46:46 PM",
    "jobs": [
        {"title": "job1", "url": "job1url", "company": "job1company", "location": "job1location", "dateUpdate": "job1date", "id": "job1id" },
        {"title": "job2", "url": "job2url", "company": "job2company", "location": "job2location", "dateUpdate": "job2date", "id": "job2id" }
    ]
};
```

Now on a server script you can insert this data on a collection:

```
JobsCollection.insert({company: dataFromXML.company ,dataFromAPI: dataFromXML});
```

In case your result is an array you can run this on a forEach loop:

```
var dataFromXMLArray = [
    {
        "company": 597837338,
        "createdAt": "3/6/2014 11:46:46 PM",
        "jobs": [
            {"title": "job1", "url": "job1url", "company": "job1company", "location":   "job1location", "dateUpdate": "job1date", "id": "job1id" },
            {"title": "job2", "url": "job2url", "company": "job2company", "location": "job2location", "dateUpdate": "job2date", "id": "job2id" }
        ]
    },
    {
        "company": 597837338,
        "createdAt": "3/6/2014 11:46:46 PM",
        "jobs": [
            {"title": "job1", "url": "job1url", "company": "job1company", "location": "job1location", "dateUpdate": "job1date", "id": "job1id" },
            {"title": "job2", "url": "job2url", "company": "job2company", "location": "job2location", "dateUpdate": "job2date", "id": "job2id" }
        ]
    }
];

dataFromXMLArray.forEach(function (data) {
    JobsCollection.insert({company: data.company, dataFromAPI: data});
});
```

Comment: this is awesome! thanks so much! So when you say `on a server script`, what do you mean?

Comment: if(Meteor.isServer){//your javascript code here} I imagine that you are calling the API from the server.

Comment: Do you want to keep the data from the API in the database?

Comment: Yes, that would be ideal to help speed things up

Comment: In that case you shouldn't use methods,  you should create a function that runs on server,  pick the data from API,  process and save to MongoDB.  Once you have the collection publish that collection to the client.